# how to add two numbers together using bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have the following file:

```
lab1:/etc/scripts# cat /tmp/tmp.PGikhA/audit.txt                                
   344 server1                                                                            
     1 server2
```

I want to be able to add the numbers from each row together - so in this case, I want to add 344 + 1 and end up with 345.

So far, I have the following steps figured out:

```
lab-1:/etc/scripts# cat /tmp/tmp.PGikhA/audit.txt |awk '{print $1}'              
344                                                                                                    
1
```

But I don't know how to add them together.  I know that I can just use $a + $b syntax, but how do I get the 344 and 1 into separate variables to do that?

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

I'm getting two values returned instead of just the one total.  Can't see what I'm doing wrong:

```
lab-1:/etc/scripts# cat /tmp/tmp.jcbiih/audit.txt | awk '{print $1}' | awk '{ sum+=$1} {print      
sum}'                                                                                                                    
344                                                                                                                      
345                                                                                                                      
lab-1:/etc/scripts# cat /tmp/tmp.jcbiih/audit.txt  | awk '{ sum+=$1} {print sum}'                  
344                                                                                                                      
345
```

Comment: Is the `355` a typo?

Comment: yes.  just typo.  will fix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do your math in awk easily. Here is an example:

```
awk '{ total+=$1 } END { print total }'
```

If you really wanted to use bash, you could use a simple loop to read one line at a time and add it up:

```
count=0 
while read -r number _; do # put the first column in "number" and discard the rest of the line
    count=$(( count + number )) 
done < /tmp/foo
echo $count
```

Comment: when i try it via command line, I'm getting both 344 and 345.  Please see edit 1

Comment: @dot You left off the "END", which tells awk to not print until it has finished processing all the data.